# Singularity of an oscillatory integral

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals, oscillatory-integral

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$, consider the following integral:
$$I(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-i|x-y|^2}}{|y|} \, dy$$
Now $I(x)$ diverges as $x$ approaches to $0$, and it seems to me that the rate of divergence is $1/|x|$. Is it this actually true? And eventually what can we say abou the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\,|x|I(x)$$
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: There is a considerable difference between $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-i|x-y|^2}}{|y|} \, dy $ and $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-i|x-y|^2}}{|y|} \, dx $.  I added $\text{“}dy\text{''}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichealHardy: Thank you for correcting the typo.